# Mongoose - populate return _id only instead of a Object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to build a schedule records the matches with two teams.

MatchSchema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

let MatchSchema = {
 MatchID: {
  type: Number,
  unique: true,
  required: true
 },
 HomeTeam: {
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Team',
 },
 AwayTeam: {
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Team',
 }
}
MatchSchema = mongoose.Schema(MatchSchema)

module.exports = mongoose.model('Match', MatchSchema, 'matches')
```

TeamSchema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

let TeamSchema = {
 TeamName: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
 }
}
TeamSchema = mongoose.Schema(TeamSchema)

module.exports = mongoose.model('Team', TeamSchema, 'matches')
```

This is the one of the match and it's team record.

Match:

```
{
 _id: "5b2084a926ca2f7f7f47a083",
 MatchID: 127299,
 HomeTeam: "5b2084a926ca2f7f7f479ff3",
 AwayTeam: "5b2084a926ca2f7f7f479fed",
 __v: 0
}
```

HomeTeam:

```
{
 _id: "5b2084a926ca2f7f7f479ff3",
 TeamName: "I am a Home Team",
 __v: 0
}
```

I want to use populate function to get the full detail of a match.

getMatch

```
const Match = require('./schema/module/match')
Match.findOne({}).populate('Team').exec((err, match) {
 console.log(match)
 /* This is the result, it return the _id of those team instead of its object:
  {
   _id: "5b2084a926ca2f7f7f47a083",
   MatchID: 127299,
   HomeTeam: "5b2084a926ca2f7f7f479ff3",
   AwayTeam: "5b2084a926ca2f7f7f479fed",
   __v: 0
  }
 */
 /*
  If I call match.populated('Team'), it showed an error with `match.populated is not a function`
 */
})
```

Thankyou guys!!!

Comment: The argument to `populate()` is not the "model name" but the "name of the path" to populate. It looks like you want "two paths", hence the existing answer on how you do that. At the most simple you can `findOne({}).populate("HomeTeam").populate("AwayTeam")` and then any other combination of options.

Comment: Oh! You save my world!! Thankyou so much!!!!